# CannotGetJdbcConnectionException with myBatis +GAE + cloudSQL

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, mybatis, google-cloud-sql

I'm new to Google App Engine. 
I'm trying to use myBatis to connect to google cloudSQL in my maven GAE.

When I tring to SELECT data from cloudSQL, I'll got Exceptions.

At first, I think there might be a SQL statement problem but I can't find it...

Then, when I changed my SQL statements into 'UPDATE',
exceptions also changed from

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Internal error.
```

to

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Internal error.
```

So I think there's no error in my SQL statements. My app can read XML file and combine SQL sentences successfully. The problem is that I can't get jdbcConnection... But why?

Could anyone give some suggestion...?

Thanks!

Here are my codes and exceptions:

exceptions

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Internal error.
### The error may exist in gcloud/myapp/sqlMap/mytestProject.xml
### The error may involve mytestProject.getAllChara
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Internal error.
at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:365)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.selectList(Unknown Source)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:188)
at gcloud.myapp.dao.CharacterDataDao.getAllChara(CharacterDataDao.java:29)
at gcloud.myapp.service.MytestProjectService.getAllCharaTest(MytestProjectService.java:36)
at gcloud.myapp.controller.MytestProjectController.to_index(MytestProjectController.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:42)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:320)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:312)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Internal error.
### The error may exist in gcloud/myapp/sqlMap/mytestProject.xml
### The error may involve mytestProject.getAllChara
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Internal error.
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:104)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:95)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:42)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:355)
... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Internal error.
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.openConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:80)
at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.getConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:66)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:279)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:69)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:56)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:141)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:105)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:81)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:101)
... 49 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Internal error.
at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.RdbmsApiProxyClient$ApiProxyBlockingInterface.makeSyncCall(RdbmsApiProxyClient.java:109)
at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.RdbmsApiProxyClient$ApiProxyBlockingInterface.openConnection(RdbmsApiProxyClient.java:71)
at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.SqlProtoClient.openConnection(SqlProtoClient.java:58)
at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:65)
at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:25)
at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver.connect(AppEngineDriver.java:83)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
... 59 more
```

controller

```
package gcloud.myapp.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import gcloud.myapp.service.MytestProjectService;

@Controller
public class MytestProjectController {

    @Autowired
    MytestProjectService mytestProjectService = new MytestProjectService();

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String to_index(Model model) throws SQLException, IOException {
        List<Map<String, String>> charaList = mytestProjectService.getAllCharaTest();
        model.addAttribute("charaList", charaList);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

service

```
package gcloud.myapp.service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import gcloud.myapp.dao.CharacterDataDao;

@Service("MytestProjectService")
public class MytestProjectService implements IMytestProjectService {

    @Autowired
    CharacterDataDao characterDataDao = new CharacterDataDao();

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, String>> getAllCharaTest() throws SQLException, IOException{
        List<Map<String, String>> charaList = characterDataDao.getAllChara();

        return charaList;
    }
}
```

dao

```
package gcloud.myapp.dao;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CharacterDataDao extends SqlSessionDaoSupport implements ICharacterDataDao {

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, String>> getAllChara() throws SQLException, IOException {
        List<Map<String, String>> charaList = getSqlSession().selectList("getAllChara");

        return charaList;
    }
}
```

sqlMap(mytestProject.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
 "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="mytestProject">
    <resultMap id="charaListMap" type="java.util.Map">
        <result property="id" column="ID" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
        <result property="name" column="CHARANAME_CH" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    </resultMap>
    <select id="getAllChara" resultMap="charaListMap">
        <![CDATA[
        SELECT ID, CHARANAME_CH
        FROM charainfo
        ]]>
    </select>
</mapper>
```

myBatis config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="gcloud/myapp/sqlMap/mytestProject.xml" />
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

spring config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- basic -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="gcloud.myapp" />

    <!-- basic -->
    <!-- view , the rules defined to resolve the view names -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <!-- basic -->
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/page/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- sqlSessionFactory -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://mytestproject:mytestproject-db/mytestproject" />
        <property name="username" value="**my user name**" />
        <property name="password" value="**my password**" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/config/SqlMapConfig.xml" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="characterDataDao" class="gcloud.myapp.dao.CharacterDataDao">
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- if without "init-param", framework will try to load the application 
            context from a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in WEB-INF directory. -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/SpringConfig.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>gcloud.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MytestProject</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <app.id>**my app id**</app.id>
        <app.version>1</app.version>

        <appengine.version>1.9.44</appengine.version>
        <gcloud.plugin.version>1.9.44</gcloud.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>

        <org.springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.3.9</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mybatis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <version>${app.version}</version>
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just localhost -->
                    <!-- address>0.0.0.0</address>
                    <port>8080</port -->
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remote debugger
                         like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
                    <!-- jvmFlags>
                      <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
              <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${gcloud.plugin.version}</version>
              <configuration>
                <set_default>true</set_default>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

2017/1/18 3:40pm update:

Not cloudSQL authorization problem.

I've tried

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://**url**/**databaseName**?user=**userName**&password=**password**");
```

and connected to database successfully.(can do SQL operations.)

Answer (score 1):

............solved it.

It's just a dataSource URL error.

in my spring-config

```
<!-- sqlSessionFactory -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://mytestproject:mytestproject-db/mytestproject" />
    <property name="username" value="**my user name**" />
    <property name="password" value="**my password**" />
</bean>
```

change

`<property name="url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://mytestproject:mytestproject-db/mytestproject" />`

to

`<property name="url" value="jdbc:google:mysql://mytestproject:us-central1:mytestproject-db/mytestproject" />`

and then it works.